# redirecting (.htaccess) is not working (NOT RELEVANT ANYMORE)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` file is not working.
It looks like the `mod_rewrite` module is not loaded.

One way to check this to run `<?php phpinfo() ?>`.

But when I do this the phpinfo pages appeart, but there's no part with 'apache2handler'.
So I can't check if the mod_rewrite module is loaded. I can't see which apache config file is loaded.

Is there anyone who can help me? I'm stuck with this problem for hours now.

This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

#exclusions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !external/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !css/

#redirect everything else
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php

Options -Indexes
```

It is placed in a subfolder of a website, like www.example.com/subfolder/
This .thaccess file works on localhost and on an other website.

This doenst result in an 500 error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    if mod_rewrite is enabled, you'll get 500 error on the server
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**
I discoverd that here is no apache running on the server, its IIS.... 
Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: You're looking in the wrong place. Check your Apache error log after attempting to load a page.  Also, post the rewrite you're attempting to accomplish. Please show the contents of your .htaccess file.

Comment: If mod_rewrite is not loaded, instruction like `RewriteEngine On` will result in a 500 error, if I'm not mistaken. So just create a htaccess file contain just that an see if you get a 500 error-page.

Comment: I can't find a log file. This because someone has installed apache and php as a retard. There are 4 different apache folders. Is there a way to check the root of the apache service that is running? On a windows system?

Answer (score 0):

If you doubt that mod_rewrite is not working on your apache, and you can't check it in phpinfo() there are plenty more ways to check it. In case you don't have terminal access to the server, you can check by .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    if mod_rewrite is enabled, you'll get 500 error on the server
</IfModule>
```